# Как правильно привязать в контроллере загрузку файла?

Tags: php, yii2

Пытаюсь разобраться с yii2 и по мануалу сделал crud новостей, все работает. Теперь пытаюсь привязать загрузчик изображения к новости и не соображу как правильно вписать код из мануала для загрузки файла в экшн контроллера:

```
 public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new GoodsCatalog();

     if (Yii::$app->request->isPost) {
        $model->imageFile = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'imageFile');
        if ($model->upload()) {
            // file is uploaded successfully
            return;
        }
    }
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);

    } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Понимаю, что неверно, прошу подсказать как совместить код для загрузки файла с имеющимся?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну например вот так.

```
 public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new Settings();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            $file = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'file');
            if (isset($file)) {
                $filename = uniqid() . '.' . $file->extension;
                $path = 'uploads/'.$filename;
                if ($file->saveAs($path)) {
                    $model->file = $path;
                    $model->value = $path;
                }
            }
            if ($model->save()) {
                Yii::$app->session->setFlash('info', 'Запись успешно добавлена');
                return $this->redirect(['index']);
            }
            else{
                foreach($model->errors as $error) Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', $error);
                return $this->redirect(['index']);
            }
        }
        else {
            foreach($model->errors as $error) Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', $error);
            return $this->redirect(['index']);
        }
    }
```

Перед этим в модели объявите переменную

```
public $file;
```

в правилах

```
 [['file'], 'file'],
```

И в представлении, используйте уже атрибут file

```
$form = ActiveForm::begin([ 'options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']]);
<?= $form->field($model, 'file')->fileInput();
...
```